# How to fix python uvicorn server returning "426 Upgrade Required"?

Tags: python, http, uvicorn

**I have a python uvicorn app which runs fine locally for my colleagues but not for me**. After running `python src/main.py`, the server connects to database and loads perfectly:

```
INFO | uvicorn.server:serve:75 - Started server process [49720]
INFO | uvicorn.lifespan.on:startup:47 - Waiting for application startup.
INFO | databases.core:connect:83 - Connected to database postgresql+asyncpg://localhost:5432/faethm_core
INFO | uvicorn.lifespan.on:startup:61 - Application startup complete.
INFO | uvicorn.server:_log_started_message:209 - Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But the server doesn't take any requests. No matter where I send it from, either `curl` command, browser request, or an API tool such as Insomnia. I always get the same response 'Upgrade Required'

For example a `curl` command:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://0.0.0.0:8000/health \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

would return

```
Upgrade Required
```

**Things I've tried but failed**

- Restarting my server and also my computer
- Trying to send requests from different browsers and tools
- Adding headers to upgrade the protocol to HTTP/2.0. The docs online aren't clear on how to do this
- Changing the http connection to https

Does anyone know where this issue is coming from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A different app was using port `8000` as a daemon running in the background.

**Solution**

Find any processes that are potentially blocking the port `8000`

```
sudo lsof -i:8080
```

Find the PID of the processes and kill them

```
kill $PID
```

You should now be able to talk to the uvicorn server properly.

**Notes**

- These daemons can get restarted even after you restart your computer, so sometimes they have to be manually killed.
- The original status code `426 Upgrade Required` didn't help at all to find the source of the problem.
- uvicorn server shouldn't have started if the port `8000` was being used by another process or daemon